# Choosing observations, which have the maximum value on the data step

Tags: sas

Table `old`:

```
date
05DEC2016   a
28NOV2016   b
22DEC2016   c
23JAN2017   d
12JAN2017   e
09JAN2017   f
25DEC2016   g
```

I need to create a new table:

```
data new;
     set old;
     ****the right code***
run;
```

so that, `new` contains rows, which have the latest date. 
So `new` is:

```
23JAN2017   d
```

I tried first finding the latest date: `latest_date = max(date)` , and then using a simple `where=`, but as you can see- this doesnt work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL is the easiest way to do this.  `max` function in the data step doesn't work across rows (as no function in the data step does); it would give you the maximum of many columns.  In the data step you could also transpose, use a hash, or just retain the saved values using across rows and compare; but SQL is very simple, using `having`.

```
data have;
format date date9.;
input date :date9. code :$1.;
datalines;
05DEC2016   a
28NOV2016   b
22DEC2016   c
23JAN2017   d
12JAN2017   e
09JAN2017   f
25DEC2016   g
;;;;
run;

proc sql;
  select date, code
    from have
    having date=max(date);
quit;
```

To do in the data step in the most simple way though you have to use `retain`, something along these lines:

```
data want;
  set have end=eof;
  retain  max_Date max_code;
  if date > max_date then do;
    max_date = date;
    max_code = code;
  end;
  if eof then output;
  format max_date date9.;
  rename 
    max_date=date 
    max_code=code
  ;
  keep max_date max_code;
run;
```

Finally, the *really* easiest way to do this specific thing is to use the [`idgroup` option in `proc means`](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/70377/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p04vbvpcjg2vrjn1v8wyf0daypfi.htm).

```
proc means data=have;
  var date;
  output out=want 
         idgroup(max(date) /* asks for the row with the maximum date */
        out[1]             /* asks for the 1 maximum date - could get more */
        (date code)=       /* asks for these two variables to be output */
  );
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to sort your data so the largest will end up at the top of your data and then take the first observation. The benefit of this method - it's super easy to understand and code. The drawback is sorting a large data set can take up a lot of time/memory.

```
data have;
format date date9.;
input date :date9. code :$1.;
datalines;
05DEC2016   a
28NOV2016   b
22DEC2016   c
23JAN2017   d
12JAN2017   e
09JAN2017   f
25DEC2016   g
;;;;
run;

proc sort data=have;
by descending date;
run;

data want;
set have (obs=1);
run;
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, that's not good, because i may have several observation with the maximum value