# All values for only most recent occurrence

Tags: sas

I am trying to extract all the Time occurrences for only the recent visit. Can someone help me with the code please.

Here is my data:

```
Obs   Name      Date       Time  

 1    Bob       2017090    1305  
 2    Bob       2017090    1015  
 3    Bob       2017081    0810  
 4    Bob       2017072    0602  
 5    Tom       2017090    1300  
 6    Tom       2017090    1010  
 7    Tom       2017090    0805  
 8    Tom       2017072    0607  
 9    Joe       2017085    1309  
10    Joe       2017081    0815
```

I need the output as:

```
Obs  Name      Date       Time  

1    Bob       2017090    1305,1015    
2    Tom       2017090    1300,1010,0805
3    Joe       2017085    1309
```

Right now my code is designed to give me only one recent entry:

```
DATA OUT2;                           
SET INP1;                          
BY DATE;                             
IF FIRST.DATE THEN OUTPUT OUT2;   
RETURN;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first sort the data by name and date.  Then I would transpose and process the results.

```
proc sort data=have;
by name date;
run;

proc transpose data=have out=temp1;
by name date;
var value;
run;

data want;
set temp1;
by name date;

if last.name;

format value $2000.;
value = catx(',',of col:);

drop col: _name_;
run;
```

You may want to further process the new `VALUE` to remove excess commas (`,`) and missing value `.`'s.

Comment: Thank yo for your solution

Answer (score 0):

Very similar to the [question yesterday from another user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43662803/choosing-observations-which-have-the-maximum-value-on-the-data-step), you can use quite a few solutions here.

SQL again is the easiest; this is *not* valid ANSI SQL and pretty much only SAS supports this, but it does work in SAS:

```
proc sql;
  select name, date, time
    from have
    group by name
    having date=max(date);
quit;
```

Even though `date` and `time` are not on the `group by` it's legal in SAS to put them on the `select`, and then SAS automatically merges (inner joins) the result of `select name, max(date) from have group by name having date=max(date)` to the original `have` dataset, returning multiple rows as needed.  Then you'd want to collapse the rows, which I leave as an exercise for the reader.

You could also simply generate a table of maximum dates using any method you choose and then merge yourself. This is probably the easiest in practice to use, in particular including troubleshooting.

The DoW loop also appeals here.  This is basically the precise SAS data step implementation of the SQL above. First iterate over that name, figure out the max, then iterate again and output the ones with that max.

```
proc sort data=have;
  by name date;
run;

data want;
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.name);
    set have;
    by name;
    max_Date = max(max_date,date);
  end;

  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.name);
    set have;
    by name;
    if date=max_date then output;
  end;
run;
```

Of course here you more easily collapse the rows, too:

```
data want;
length timelist $1024;
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.name);
    set have;
    by name;
    max_Date = max(max_date,date);
  end;

  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (last.name);
    set have;
    by name;
    if date=max_date then timelist=catx(',',timelist,time);
    if last.name then output;
  end;
run;
```

Comment: Thank yo for your solution

Answer (score 0):

If the data is sorted then just retain the first date so you know which records to combine and output.

```
proc sort data=have ;
  by name descending date time; 
run;
data want ;
  set have ;
  by name descending date ;
  length timex $200 ;
  retain start timex;
  if first.name then do;
    start=date;
    timex=' ';
  end;
  if date=start then do;
    timex=catx(',',timex,time);
    if last.date then do;
      output;
      call missing(start,timex);
    end;
  end;
  drop start time ;
  rename timex=time ;
run;
```

Comment: Hi Tom,  thanks for your code. I tried it and it works fine except for the output has trailing blanks in it. I tried using compress and strip functions but it does not help.

Comment: Trailing blanks? SAS variables are fixed length. They ALWAYS have trailing blanks.

Comment: Just got it resolved. I was doing a compress after CATX, which didn't seem to work. But when I did a compress in the PUT statement it gave me the desired results.

Comment: PUT statement should by default trim character variables. Unless you added a format to tell it to do something different.